# tricky 'simplification'

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This popped up in a  quantum mechanics assignment. I've committed to an hour of attempt and nothing good came out. I'd thought I'd seek help before being driven up the wall.

I need to show that

$\frac{16\left ( 2m\left ( v_{0}-E \right )\left ( 2mE \right ) \right )}{\left (  \left ( 2m\left ( v_{0}-E \right )+2mE \right )\right )^{2}}$

reduces to

$\frac{16E\left ( v_{0}-E \right )}{v_{0}^{2}}$

Would some kind soul help me?

Comment: the inside of the squared bracket in the denominator is equivalent to $2mv_0$. does that help?

Comment: Don't expand anything, just pull all of the common factors of $2m$ out the front in both numerator and denominator, cancel them, and then look at what's left inside the parentheses on the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

We have: $$(2m(v_0 - E) + 2mE)^2 = (2m)^2 ((v_0 - E) + E) = 4m^2((v_0 - E) + E)^2 = 4m^2 v_0^2$$

And so $$\frac{16(2m(v_0 - E) 2m E)}{(2m(v_0 - E) + 2mE)^2} = \frac{16 (4m^2) (v_0 - E) E}{4m^2 v_0^2} = \frac{16 (v_0 - E) E}{v_0}$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\frac{16\left ( 2m\left ( v_{0}-E \right )\left ( 2mE \right ) \right )}{\left (  \left ( 2m\left ( v_{0}-E \right )+2mE \right )\right )^{2}} 
&= 16\frac{4m^2E(v_0-E)}{4m^2((v_0-E) + E)^2} \\
&= 16\frac{E(v_0-E)}{v_{0}^{2}} \\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Hints take $2m$ common from denominator $4m^2$ get cancelled by $2m.2m$ in the numerator. Then using $(a+b)^2$ we have denominator as $(v-E)^2+2E(v-E)+E^2=v^2-2Ev+E^2-2Ev-2E^2+E^2=v^2$ thats it. Note i have taken $v=v_0$